# Defining "types" of objects

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I'm trying to implement a class that may have only a defined set of objects. These Objects obviously have all the same properties, but only differ in the values of these properties.
As an example think of class car. It has the properties name and ps. It should be (only) possible to create the following Objects:

- car with name:'Porsche', PS:350;
- car with name:'BMW', PS:250;

It should not be possible to initialize i.e. a car with name:'Porsche', PS:500;
This list might change or expand while coding is continued.

Is it a good Idea to create the types as subclasses of car, setting it's values in the constructor? Or would it be smart to set up some kind of factory / creator pattern?

Thanks a lot for your ideas
Simon

Comment: The classical pattern here is the Factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to hide the details of the construction process. Since you don't have subclasses, the GoF solutions with Factory, Prototype and Builder are likely over-design.

I solved this problem in a Java game before with static initializers. The following example shows configurations of Weapons that are standard in the game.

```
public class Weapon {
    ...
    public static final Weapon 
        DAGGER = new Weapon("Dagger", 0, 1, -1, true, false), 
        RAPIER = new Weapon("Rapier", 9, 1, 0, false, false),
        CLUB = new Weapon("Club", 9, 1, 0, true, false),
    ...
}
```

You access the objects as `Weapon.DAGGER`, etc. I didn't do it, but could/should have made the constructor private. Thus, others can't instantiate invalid variants of the weapon class.

If you needed to have multiple instances of the same configuration of object, an alternative constructor could take an enumeration value, e.g., PORSCHE350, and it would construct the proper values for that object.

The *extreme* case of this kind of control would be using something like the [Object Constraint Language (OCL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language).

Comment: yeah, private constructor is the key here.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Example is very close to my problem. Hope nobody is offended when I change my acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

To create subclasses will depend on your needs. Basically if you need behaviors that differ in some way, go ahead and create subclases by using a Factory.

If you just need to fill up an Car with values that depends on other values, you may use the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

If your objects values are concrete and you just need to start from a sort of template, use a [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

Comment: Thx for your answer and the links. All Objects must have exactly the same behaviour and the same properties. Only the values of these properities are different, defined sets. To be honest, I don't understand the disadvantage of a static create method that gets passed a type string and returns a defined object of the class. Nevertheless I think I will check the prototype.

Comment: disagree strongly. these are just 3 random design patterns that are able to construct objects. answer gives no real explanation why any of them help with the problem at hand. OP, please use something like the answer with static members but also make the constructor private, then the compiler + language will do the work for you instead of writing a bunch of code for no reason